# Question about hiding commitment scheme for integers

Tags: discrete-logarithm, terminology, commitments

Given a generic group $\mathbb{G}$ of an unknown order (such as a $3000$-bit RSA group) and a randomly generated element $g \in \mathbb{G}$, is the commitment scheme $\mathrm{Com}(x)= g^x$ not considered to be a *computationally* hiding scheme for sufficiently large (say, $128$-bit) integers?

I thought it was computationally hiding since retrieving $x$ from $\mathrm{Com}(x)$ would mean solving the discrete log problem. But it seems it is not considered to be computationally hiding in the literature, which seems confusing to me.

Comment: "But it seems it is not considered to be computationally hiding in the literature, which seems confusing to me."-> Could you add a reference about this sentence.

Comment: Given a candidate $x'$ and a commitment $c$, does the commitment scheme let you verify wherever $c$ is a commitment to $x'$?

Comment: @Maeher Thanks. I think that was my confusion. 

I thought the computationally hiding property just meant recovering $x$ from the commitment was infeasible. 

It seems you also should not be able to verify whether $\mathrm{Com}(x)$ is the commitment for $x$ in order for it to be computationally hiding. That explains the need for a blinding factor.